# Vegetables are sprouting way ahead of schedule -- what gives?

Tags: vegetables, germination, seedlings

I bought some seed-starting contraptions from the home center and planted vegetable & herb seeds in them. That was on Sunday (four days ago). The packaging said that sprouts should emerge within 7 days. Things were starting to happen within **two** days, and as of this morning (Thursday 4/16), here's what's going on:

[image: sprouts_1]

[image: sprouts_2]

Is this normal, or are these seeds precocious for some reason? Or maybe I planted them too shallowly?

Answer (score 2):

Well, 'within 7 days' is exactly what some of them have done, so they are bang on schedule; it means **during** that time period, not **at** seven days, so it might be day two, three, four or whatever. It's fine, seeds are clearly healthy and keen to grow, the conditions are optimal for germination and that's a good thing. The time to worry is if nothing has germinated after two weeks...

Answer (score 1):

And, most seeds sprout according to temperature ( if damp). So your location was relatively warm , compared to the garden soil which may be about 60 F depending on depth and location. I used to sprout seeds in an oven that had a gas pilot light which kept the oven at about 90 F, most seeds were up in 48 hours. Caution: do not turn the oven on at this time.